# Unable to access Couldera Manager 5 web console after installation

Tags: hadoop, admin

I am setting up a hadoop cluster(2.6) on CentOS 7 machine with three nodes, cluster is running fine now. However, I am not able to access the Cloudera manager(5.6) web console after completing the CM installation though its services seems to be running.

Below are my findings, please help me what could be the possible reasons:

All process are up and running !

```
[root@vm-txxxxxx1 ~]# jps
27978 ResourceManager
15368 Main
27052 Jps
27400 DataNode
27639 SecondaryNameNode
28106 NodeManager
27258 NameNode
```

**Firewall stopped**

```
[root@vm-txxxxx1 ~]# service iptables stop
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl stop  iptables.service

[root@vm-txxxxxx1 ~]# service iptabes status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  iptabes.service
iptabes.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
Mar 24 19:24:05 vm-txxxxx1 systemd[1]: Stopped IPv4 firewall with iptables.
```

**Listening on port 7180 and tested the same locally**

```
[root@vm-txxxxxx1 ~]# netstat -tulpn | grep 7180
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7180            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15368/java

[root@vm-txxxxx1 ~]# telnet localhost 7180
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

**SELINUX Disabled:**

```
[root@vm-txxxxxx1 ~]# getenforce
Disabled
```

**Hostfile entries**

```
[root@vm-txxxxxx1 ~]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4
172.16.xx.x1 vm-txxxxxx1
172.16.xx.x2 vm-xxxxxxx2
172.16.xx.x4 del1-vm-poc04
```

**Verify if Cloudera Manager is running:**

```
[root@vm-txxxxxx1 ~]# service cloudera-scm-server status
cloudera-scm-server.service - LSB: Cloudera SCM Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/cloudera-scm-server)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2016-03-22 17:09:55 IST; 2 days ago
  Process: 15344 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/cloudera-scm-server start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 22 17:09:50 vm-txxxxxx1 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Cloudera SCM Server...
Mar 22 17:09:50 vm-txxxxx1 su[15366]: (to cloudera-scm) root on none
Mar 22 17:09:55 vm-txxxxxx1 cloudera-scm-server[15344]: Starting cloudera-scm-server:...]
Mar 22 17:09:55 vm-txxxxxx1 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Cloudera SCM Server.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

**Below are the lines from Cloudera servers logs**

```
[root@vm-txxxxx1 ~]# tail -f /var/log/cloudera-scm-server/cloudera-scm-server.log

2016-03-24 18:21:00,398 INFO StaleEntityEviction:com.cloudera.server.cmf.StaleEntityEvictionThread: Reaped total of 0 deleted commands
2016-03-24 18:21:00,400 INFO StaleEntityEviction:com.cloudera.server.cmf.StaleEntityEvictionThread: Found no commands older than 2014-03-25T12:51:00.399Z to reap.
2016-03-24 18:21:00,400 INFO StaleEntityEviction:com.cloudera.server.cmf.StaleEntityEvictionThread: Wizard is active, not reaping scanners or configurators
```

I am accessing the Cloudera Manager page http://172.16.xx.1x:7180
at the end it says "*The connection has timeout*", it looks like my http request is not able to reach out to the server, that's why nothing comes up in the logs. Please suggest if I am missing something.

Thanks in advance!

> @Havnar: Thanks for the suggestion, I am confirming SSL is not enabled now
>   and sharing the curl result.

```
[root@vm-txxxx1 ~]# curl -i -u 'admin:admin' http://localhost:7180/api/v1/tools/echo
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Expires: Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie: CLOUDERA_MANAGER_SESSIONID=1etaj5o42vprlndf43ua7rbaf;Path=/;HttpOnly
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Fri, 25 Mar 2016 05:50:36 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(6.1.26.cloudera.4)

{
  "message" : "Hello, World!"
```

I tried stop and restarted the cloudera service, nothing find suspicious, there was one warning which is looking little bit suspicious, search them google, nothing looks relevant.

```
[root@vm-txxxxx1 ~]# vi /var/log/cloudera-scm-server/cloudera-scm-server.log

2016-03-24 20:22:29,002 WARN main:org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory: HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache]; using defaults.
2016-03-24 20:22:28,581 INFO main:org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder: HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

@Havnar : I didn't get what do you meant by "try a cat on the machine running the CM", let me know if anything else need to be checked.

Thanks

Comment: try a cat on the machine running the CM. It could be that the port is not open. Did you enable SSL perhaps? you could try restarting the CM `service cloudera-scm-server restart`. Try a `tail -f ` on the log file during the restart.

Comment: @Harnvar:  SSL was not enabled earlier, enabled it now:

Comment: @Havnar: I tried stop and restarted the cloudera service, nothing find suspicious, there was one warning which is looking little bit suspicious, search them google, nothing looks relevant. posted logs above...

Comment: I didn't get what do you meant by "try a cat on the machine running the CM", let me know if anything else need to be checked.

Comment: HTTPS runs on a Different Port than 7180, but best disable it. Sorry i meant curl instead of Cat earlier.

Comment: @Havnar: `[root@vm-txxxxx1 ~]# curl -i http://localhost:7180
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Expires: Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie: CLOUDERA_MANAGER_SESSIONID=1i3yf6lnuy68x1umd6svp5v7tg;Path=/;HttpOnly
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Last-Modified: Fri, 12 Feb 2016 03:18:30 GMT
Content-Length: 63
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=3600,public
Server: Jetty(6.1.26.cloudera.4)

<head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/cmf/"></head>`

Comment: Curl output doesn't complaint about anything, it looks fine.

Comment: What about a curl from the client you are trying with, Also try an up to date broser(Firefox, chrome,...)

Comment: @Havnar, I don't have wget or any other substitute of curl installed on my windows system. I simply tried telnet to port 7180, which doesn't work, but I have allowed everything from server. Do you know what could be the possible cause? I am using firefox browser, which is 45,0 up to date.

Comment: In that case it's not a config issue but a matter of network/security issues. Enable portforwarding in case your client is in a different subnet. Also allow the port in your firewall.